# How to make Asynchronous nonblocking thread FACEBOOK in Android

Tags: android, facebook

i am trying to make facebook asynchronous non blocking thread in android. due to which our UI is run separate thread but i am unable to do that can any one tell me how to do that.
and If possible pleade give me one example. 
Thanks.........

Comment: What's a facebook asynchronous non blocking thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about the Facebook but to access to the ui component from the other thread-

```
public class Dictionary extends Activity{       
    Handler mhandler;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Handler mhandler = new Handler();
        SearchThread thread = new SearchThread();
        thread.setParent(this);
        thread.setHandler(mhandler);
   }
   public void notifyItemChanged(ArrayList<ListItem> lItems){
   //write code relating to ui here
   }
   private class SearchThread extends Thread{
      private Handler handler;
      Dictionary parent;

      public void setParent(Dictionary parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
      }

      public void setHandler(Handler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
      }

      @Override
      public void run() {
          final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                parent.notifyItemChanged(listItems);
            }                   
        };
        handler.post(mUpdateResults);
  }
 }
```